# Maplex Label Engine Places Labels Too Close Together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.4, maplex

I'm currently trying to label major arterial highways such as interstates and U.S. Routes. I want to have multiple labels per object but Maplex seems to want to cluster the labels together. I've tried setting a minimum duplicate label distance but this has had little effect. To clarify, I don't have any duplicate objects (like multiple segments of the same highway) as I've merged them together in an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using street labeling or just regular labels? Are you using page units or map units for your minimum duplicate distance? Is the over labeling everywhere or in certain parts of the map (e.g. edges or at intersections)? I have gotten this to work great with small segments, but it was a few versions back (10.1) and I don't map streets much anymore.

Comment: I'm using regular labels, however I'm using the interstate and U.S. Route symbols respectively. I wasn't using map units but rather inches and then points. The labels do seem to cluster near the edges of the map but not so much intersections with other features.